# One column image need to place at last page(two column Document)

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, two-column

One column image need to place at last page(two column Document) but it always goes to new page, I don't like use multicols, is it any solutions for this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-18]
\balance
\begin{figure*}[tb] 
\centering
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth, height=120pt]{example-image-a}}
\label{fig:Fig5}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

a `figure*` always goes to at the earliest the following page, but you can move it earlier in the source so that it appears on the page you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14]
\balance
\begin{figure*}[tb] 
\centering
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth, height=120pt]{example-image-a}}
\label{fig:Fig5}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[15-18]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the balance package seems to have issues with preserving baselineskip in the final paragraph

Comment: David Carlisle My requirement is After the figure no text is allowed.

Comment: @Shalu then latex will place the figure on a page on its own.

Comment: This is the problem I am facing even it have enough space it's move to next page, after the figure no text is allowed is it any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

See, if the `stfloats` package can help:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14]
\balance
\begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.9\paperwidth, height=120pt]{example-image-a}}
\label{fig:Fig5}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[15-18]
\end{document}
```

Last page looks as follows:

[image]